# Image storage - better way

Tags: php, file-upload, seo

in my project i store images(uploaded by user) in a folder, for each respective product.

For example to add a product a form is displayed to user. User fills details about product and selects some images from his computer(5 or more pictures). When submitted i will store product details in a table called `Products`. For images uploaded, i create a folder like this: `http://mysite.com/uploads/123/` here `123` is product id of product that is newly added. And all images are saved inside it.

Questions:

- how to keep track of images uploaded(or filenames of it) for later displaying? that is, when a new product is added, my script will create a fancy uri text. Eg: `http://mysite.com/this-is-my-new-product`. So if user visits this link, it should show all images belonging to that product. For this, I have to keep a separate table with product ids and the filenames ? And query this table and echo filenames from it? Or is it good to scan the folder(example: `http://mysite.com/uploads/123/*.jpg`) and echo images one by one, ie. without using a separate table ?
- is it ok if use the fancy uri for the filenames of images? Example: `/uploads/123/this-is-my-new-product1.jpg`, `/uploads/123/this-is-my-new-product2.jpg`, `/uploads/123/this-is-my-new-product3.jpg`, etc. ? So, users will see path of first image as `http://mysite.com/uploads/123/this-is-my-new-product1.jpg`. This is physical address. Will it help in SEO ? Or it is bad practice ? If this is good, then to list all images i should use [scanddir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) ?

Please guide me through correct path. Thanku

Comment: I think it would be painful to update the image names of a product. So, 1. sql: `update products set name='New product name' where...`, 2. `php: $images=glob("uploads/123/*"); foreach($images as $image) rename($image, $new_name);` etc. Just a notice.

Comment: And deleting an image or product. `$images=glob("uploads/123/*"); foreach($images as $image) if($image==$the_image_that_will_be_deleted) unlink($image);`. As you see; updating, renaming deleting, everything. And more... Actually, it is complicated to store the images relying on product names or something else that is not constant. So, if you do this for SEO, forget it. Load your product images on your server using an uniq hash implementation that fixed a length like 32 chars (md5), store these hashes on db AND JUST SIMPLY APPLY "alt" ATTRIBUTE ON YOUR IMAGES. That would be enough for SE bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you either need some link between the data and the images, or be prepared to scan the folder and just output what you find. The latter is more computationally expensive and not altogether graceful as an approach.

A compromise might be to rename the images, as they're uploaded, 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc and then simply log in the DB the *number* of images uploaded. Example:

```
if ($res = $db->query("query to get product row here")) {
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($row['num_imgs'])) {
        for($i=0; $i<$row['num_imgs']; $i++) {
            $img_path = $product_folder_uri."/".($i+1).".jpg";
            if (file_exists($img_path))
                echo "<img src='".$img_path."' />";
        }
    }
}
```

If you were unwilling to rename the images from their uploaded names, you would need to log their names in the DB, presumably in their own table and via a foreign key to the product table.

A final option would be to store the images as blobs in the database, but I'm no DB expert so I don't know how widespread or advisable this is.

Comment: Well storing images as blobs will be a bad idea if the server has limited memory allocated for mysql, specially in shared hosting

Comment: Yeap, true enough. Just floating it as an idea.

Comment: Thanku. i like this idea of storing number in a field with product.

Answer (score 1):

1.i suggest you to create another table to store image filenames with product ids.

2.for image filenames, use some unique random name along with the orginal file name, you can use PHP's uniqid to generate filenames, or you can use timestamps to name the file. Lets say if the image name is myimage.jpg, it would be better to save it as 23208349984_myimage.jpg

Comment: 1. so to get the image names from second table, i should use a second query? Is it possible to join both tables data ?
2. I saw a site storing with fancy uri as filename(with 1,2,3, numbers at end). So that is not good? OS have limitation in filename character count?

Comment: I think you have to use second query, as we have more than 1 image for a single product joining table will be a hassle, first you loop through the product, fetch product id, and then make another query within the loop with this product id to fetch images from another table. 
Again, you can use anyway of naming the file as doesnot make impact anywhere. Just use what is feasible for you and what you are comfortable with

Comment: If any of the solution worked for you, please accept it as a solved, so that people will understand that the problem has been solved